# Trouble rendering a sprite with pixi.js on iOS 8

Tags: ios, pixi.js

I have a sprite that loads into a stage in chrome and safari, but not in iOS 8 device or simulator.  The canvas appears, but it is always white (even when I specify red).   And nothing seems to render in it.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
var renderer = PIXI.autoDetectRenderer(400, 300);

elem[0].appendChild(renderer.view);

var stage = new PIXI.Stage(0xFF0000);

var wheelTexture = PIXI.Texture.fromImage("/static/img/special/thing.png");
var wheelSprite = new PIXI.Sprite(wheelTexture);
stage.addChild(wheelSprite);
requestAnimationFrame(animate);

function animate() {
  renderer.render(stage);

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```

To put this question another way, I challenge you to draw a sprite on a canvas using Pixi.js in iOS8 and then tell me how it was accomplished.  I seem to be able to run most webgl demos and such in the iOS8 simulator, but this basic Pixi.js code doesn't work...

**UPDATE:** 
It turns out that it is rendering everything fine, with the exception that if I don't use a pure black background on the container, it basically renders the stage and everything inside of it white so you can't see it.

Comment: Yeah I am pretty sure Pixi just does not support iOS8 even though they say they do.  I have code in pure webgl that is working, but the pixi equivalent is just a blank canvas.

Comment: For me, my game and the examples on pixijs.com/examples work on iOS on an iPhone 5c. Not saying there isn't a problem, but it doesn't seem to be as simple as not working at all on ios8

Comment: UPDATE: I've narrowed the issue down to the background color.  For some reason, if the container background color is not black, and the stage isn't white, then it will render the stage with all the colors tending towards white (depending on how light or dark the background container color is).  So there is some kind of blending issue happening on iOS 8, but not in Safari desktop.

Comment: Looks like it might have been fixed in the dev version of PIXI: https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/commit/3e9c010e0fb55c340009ebc27813a9dccb910b09

Answer (score 4):

The dev branch of pixi now works like a champ in ios8. I also pushed a patch up to the master branch too as it is quite an important fix.

https://github.com/GoodBoyDigital/pixi.js/commit/b29acff1455117567440acdb9fc16f9d1d5670db

Turned out to be a simple case of ios8 not liking it when I set the webGL colorMask alpha channel to false